# Has_Many_Through & Active_Record_Collection_Proxy ERROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, rails-activerecord, model-associations

I am new to rails and am working on my first little project

I have 3 models in my rails app :

Restaurant <- (master model)

Menu <- (relates directly to restaurant, restaurant can only have 1 menu)

Items <- (relates directly to menu, menu has many items)

I am having trouble setting up associations & just can't seem to get it right. My Models are as follows :

```
 class Restaurant < ApplicationRecord  
  has_one :menu
  has_many :items, through: :menus

class Menu < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :restaurant
  has_many :items


class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :menu
```

When I try to render a partial view on the page by calling the classes I get 
"

> undefined method `items' for #
>   Menu::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x3a74d08>

Which I'm doing by :

```
        <%= render @menus%>
        <%= render @items %>
```

I have success displaying the MENU partial, but displaying the items throws up the undefined method error.

Here is my restaurant controller :

```
  def show
    @menus = Menu.where(:restaurant_id => @restaurant.id)
    @items = Item.where(:menu_id => @menus.id)
  end
```

I have spent a lot of time trying to adjust the associations with no luck. Thank you.

Comment: might be in your if statement.  You are calling `@menus` but you want to only be calling one `@menu` to get the items for that specific menu. If you actually have multiple `menus` then you should loop over those and then call `.items` for each instance of `menu`. In this scenario, your `render @items` should probably be `render @menu.items` because from this it doesn't look like `@items` is defined.

Comment: Restaurant Controller = def show @menus = Menu.where(:restaurant_id => @restaurant.id) end

Answer (score 0):

Try :menu instead of :menus

```
class Restaurant < ApplicationRecord  
  has_one :menu
  has_many :items, through: :menu
```